# No method error in Marionettte/Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am getting "no method 'result' backbone.marionette.js:402 error". here's the trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'result' backbone.marionette.js:402

Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.buildItemView backbone.marionette.js:402
Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.addItemView backbone.marionette.js:360
Marionette.CollectionView.Marionette.View.extend.showCollection backbone.marionette.js:314
```

...

in backbone.marionette.js:

```
// Build an `itemView` for every model in the collection. 
buildItemView: function(item, ItemView){
var itemViewOptions = _.result(this, "itemViewOptions");
    ***Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj) { return new wrapper(obj); } has no method 'result' ***
var options = _.extend({model: item}, itemViewOptions);
var view = new ItemView(options);
return view;
backbone. },
```

my calling code:

```
MyApp.module("CatalogsApp.Pasteboard", function(Pasteboard, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    var CatalogListView, CatalogView;
    CatalogView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      tagName: "div",
      className: "catalog-cell",
      template: "catalogs/catalog"
    });
    CatalogListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
      tagName: "div",
      className: "paste-board",
      itemView: catalogView
    });
    Pasteboard.showCatalogs = function(catalogList) {
      var catalogListView;
      catalogListView = new CatalogListView({
        collection: catalogList
      });
      return MyApp.layout.main.show(catalogListView);
    };
  });
```

if anyone has any clue what might be the issue here causing the type error - be great to get thoughts. i am almost there i can tell. catalogList collection seems fine - populated from server. i know this might be hard to decipher, but maybe someone has some idea of how to approach solving.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have the latest underscore.js version. the 'result' function was added in v1.3.3

Comment: This was definitely the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your class definition when you do this `var catalogListView;`.

The convention is to capitalize names for your class definitions, like this:

```
MyApp.module("CatalogsApp.Pasteboard", function(Pasteboard, MyApp, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    var CatalogListView, CatalogView;
    CatalogView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      tagName: "div",
      className: "catalog-cell",
      template: "catalogs/catalog"
    });
    CatalogListView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
      tagName: "div",
      className: "paste-board",
      itemView: CatalogView
    });
    Pasteboard.showCatalogs = function(catalogList) {
      var catalogListView;
      catalogListView = new CatalogListView({
        collection: catalogList
      });
      return MyApp.layout.main.show(catalogListView);
    };
  });
```

Comment: i have to apologize, because i actually have those capitalized in my code (and just edited above). i had to find/replace to change the names of vars due to client confidentiality. When I did this I got the caps screwed up. The above code is corrected as such and so the error/issue still applies to this updated code. tx for spotting this.

Comment: Just one more to correct, during the view instantiation you still have `new catalogListView`

Comment: and also in CollectionView class `itemView: catalogView`